# Embedded Matlab functions in Simulink - Diagnostic Viewer misbehaves

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm implementing a few embedded Matlab function blocks in a Simulink model (Matlab R2014a). Very often, when I try to compile the model, the Diagnostic Viewer reports an error in the Matlab function which has already been corrected. In those cases it's not rare for the Viewer to reference a line of code that no longer even exists in the Matlab function. I have tried manually erasing all build files prior to compiling the model, but that often doesn't help. About the only thing that works is restarting Matlab. Can somebody shed light as to what the issue may be?

Comment: Is it a function called from the block or the code is directly in the MATLAB code for the block? If it is not in block is the file in network drive that might not be updating immediately in local machine? Is the external file saved before you run the model? You can try "clear functions" and see if that works if the function is in a separate MATLAB file.

Comment: The code is implemented directly in the Matlab block. Here's another weird, related scenario: the Simulink model causes a run-time error, for instance a non-finite drivative. I correct the source of the error in the code, delete all build files, rebuild the Simulink model and run it. The same run-time error is reported at exactly the same time in the simulation. Then I exit Matlab, restart it, rebuild the exact same Simulink model and run it. Now the model runs without a problem.